# I am getting Error in checkname: Must use single string to index into reactivevalues when the indices do seem to be single strings

Tags: r, shiny

In my app, I have created a UI output which is a set of independent radioButtons. Using these, the user selects a column, and that column gets plotted as a scatterplot using renderPlot (code for this not included). When the user clicks on any of the points on this plot, I wish to find the index of the row corresponding to that point, in the dataframe corresponding to file_num. However, I am getting a "Error in checkName: Must use single string to index into reactivevalues" error. Can someone please point out the cause of the error and how to fix it?

I think the error is related to the paste0 function, but not sure. Also, printing out the "row_index" variable gave output "integer(0)" and terminated the session

```
server <- function(input, output, session){
  
#--------------------------------------------  
  output$Variables <- renderUI({
    req(files_list_creator_1())
    numVar <- asInt(length(files_list_creator_1()))
    
    taglist = list(radioButtons(inputId = "file_num", label ="File number", choices = c("Choices will appear here")))
    for (i in 1:numVar){
      taglist = append(taglist, list(radioButtons(inputId = paste0("x_var_of_file", i, sep ="_") , label = paste("x Variables of file", i, sep = "-"), choices = c("Choices will appear here"))))
      taglist = append(taglist, list(radioButtons(inputId = paste0("y_var_of_file", i, sep ="_") , label = paste("y Variables of file", i, sep = "-"), choices = c("Choices will appear here"))))
      
    }
    tagList(taglist) 
    
  })
#---------------------------------------------------------  
  
  selected_point_index = reactiveValues()
  near_point_results = reactiveValues()
  observeEvent(input$plot_click_1,{
    req(files_list_creator_1())
      i = as.integer(input$file_num)
      x_names = input[[paste0("x_var_of_file", i, sep ="_")]]
      y_names = input[[paste0("y_var_of_file", i, sep ="_")]]
      x_cord = input$plot_click_1$x
      y_cord = input$plot_click_1$y
      df = files_list_creator_1()[[i]]
      row_index <- which(df$x_names == x_cord & df$y_names == y_cord)
      selected_point_index[[paste0("near_point_of_file", i, sep ="_")]] = row_index
      print(row_index)      
    
  })
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a minimal (!!) working app code and snippet of your data or some fake data if needed. As is your issue is not reproducible, i.e. we can't run your code and we can't figure out what's the issue or how this could be fixed.

Comment: @stefan I will do that, thank you. But can you please check the line row_index <- which (df.....), because using print statements on df and y_cord gave correct outputs, so maybe there is an obvious or basic syntactical error in that line?

Comment: From the error message I can only guess that `paste0("near_point_of_file", i, sep ="_")` is a vector of length > 1.

Answer (score 2):

##### Row Index

`row_index <- which(df$x_names == x_cord & df$y_names == y_cord)` does not work properly because you didn't click *exactly* on its y- and x-coordinate. Your clicked point is off by some decimals. Therefore, there is no row, where `df$x_names == x_cord`.

To access the real coordinates use `nearPoints`. You can see an example in the app below.

##### Error

The error "Error in checkName: Must use single string to index into reactivevalues" means that the `i` in `paste0("near_point_of_file", i, sep ="_")` is of length > 1 (as mentioned by @stefan). There is probably something wrong with your radioButtons because in my version it works just fine:

```
ui <- basicPage(
        plotOutput("plot1", click = "plot_click"),
        verbatimTextOutput("info", placeholder = T),
        radioButtons(inputId = "file_num", label ="File number", choices = c(1,2,3)),
        verbatimTextOutput("info2", placeholder = T)
)

server <- function(input, output) {
        selected_point_index = reactiveValues()

        output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
                plot(mtcars$wt, mtcars$mpg)
        })

        observeEvent(input$plot_click,{
                i = as.integer(input$file_num)

                #this is the coordinate your provide for which(...)
                x_cord = input$plot_click$x
                #while this is the true coordinate. 
                x_true = nearPoints(mtcars, input$plot_click, xvar = "wt", yvar = "mpg")$wt

                output$info <- renderPrint({
                        if(length(x_true) == 0) return(NULL)
                        setNames(c(x_cord, x_true), c("clicked_coordinate", "true_coordinate"))
                })

                row_index <- rownames(nearPoints(mtcars, input$plot_click, xvar = "wt", yvar = "mpg"))

                #It works with my simple radioButtons input.
                selected_point_index[[paste("near_point_of_file", i, sep ="_")]] <-  row_index

                output$info2 <- renderPrint({
                        selected_point_index[[paste("near_point_of_file", i, sep ="_")]]
                })


        })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I found out that the error was occurring due to an indexing error in some other block of code. I was indexing a list of reactiveValues using ```[[i]]``` where i is an integer, but it should have been indexed using ```[[paste0(i)]]```. Also, using ```[[str(i)]]``` doesn't help.